# Como usar BackHandler (react-native)?

Tags: react-native

Comecei a aprender sobre react-native a pouco tempo e criei um aplicativo. Nele coloquei um botão para voltar de cena que funciona normalmente, porém quando tento utilizar o botão de voltar do celular o aplicativo é fechado.

Descrobri que tenho que utilizar o comando BackHandler para fazer o botão do celular voltar a cena também, mas até agora não achei um exemplo de código que fale exatamente quais partes devem ser adaptadas para cada código e quais devem ser mantidas

Esse é o exemplo de código que achei:

```
return (
        componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress', () => {
            const { dispatch, nav } = this.props
            if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) 
                return false
            dispatch({ type: 'Back' })
                return true
        })
    }

componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('backPress')
    }
```

Mas quando tentei colocar para rodar deu o erro "Unespected toekn" na linha da comando "componentDidMount(){".

O que tenho que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o erro esteja no local onde você sobrescreveu as funções componentWillMount() e do componentWillUnmount()

A estrutura correta deve ser algo como:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, BackHandler } from 'react-native';

class MyScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress', () => {
      const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
      if (shouldCloseApp(nav)) 
        return false;
      dispatch({ type: 'Back' });
      return true;
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('backPress')
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View> {...} </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Coloquei desse jeito em todas as cenas porém apareceu o erro "Can't find variable: shouldCloseApp", como faço para declarar?

Comment: Não sei a que ela se refere. Achei que fazia relação a alguma parte do seu código. Se você quer apenas voltar a cena, basta trocar tudo que está dentro do handler do Listener para this.props.navigator.pop() (Verificando se this.props.navigator é diferente de null antes.

Comment: Mudei como sugerido, agora o aplicativo começa a voltar de cena mas antes de terminar o processo ele fecha. Por acaso você sabe o que devo fazer?

Comment: Talvez você pudesse dar mais detalhes, esse fechamento é simplesmente fechar o aplicativo ou ele está dando algum crash? Eu precisaria de mais informações para poder ajudar.

Comment: Não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro, quando clico no botão voltar do celular a tela começa a voltar, mas antes que carregue a tela anterior o aplicativo fecha sem deixar nenhum recado.

Comment: gravei um vídeo para mostrar o que esta acontecendo: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilbLG37lhCo)